# MacBook sleeps on changing lid inclination

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have a MacBook Pro 13 inch early 2015 model. For the last few days, my MacBook started to sleep when I change the inclination angle of the lid. On repeated pressing of the Shutdown button, it wakes up.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know the root cause?

Comment: Anything you can add would be helpful.  Any recent upgrades, macbook sleeve/cover, certain places this happens, sleeping at same lid position is duplicated etc.?

Comment: Can you please comment on what the outcome was?

Comment: I didn't try anything. After few days, I didn't face this issue anymore. I am not sure why it happened and what caused the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it comes down to one of a few things. Here are a few based on the info there is to go on.

**Reset the System Management Controller**

To resolve nearly every power related issue on a Mac you can reset the SMC (or System Management Controller0. This will dump and reset settings for anything power management related, and is long known to resolve problems with things like fans, heat, sleep problems, display issues, etc.

On any modern MacBook Pro or MacBook Air with a built-in battery, which is just about all of them nowadays, this is how you do that:

1. Shut down the Mac and connect it to your MagSafe adapter and a wall
   outlet as usual
2. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Power button</kbd> at the same time for 5 seconds.
3. Release all keys at the same time
4. Boot the Mac as usual

**Try a PRAM/NVRAM Reset**

If the above trick failed, a PRAM reset can at times do the trick, and this is done upon restarting the Mac similar to an SMC reset:

1. Reboot the Mac and as soon as you hear the boot chime, hold and keep down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys together
2. When you hear the boot sound again, the PRAM has been reset so you can now let go of the keys and let the Mac boot up again as usual

**Lastly, it can be hardware that is beginning to fail or failing.**

A good way to check is by running Apple Diagnostics located on your computer.
There is a process in which it should be run and you can read the full documentation at [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731).